# how to declare variable in scala lambda expression

Tags: scala

in the method reduceByKey(), I was required to pass a function like this:

```
func:((String,Int),(String,Int))=>(String,Int)
```

and my code is

```
reduceByKey(((s1:String,i1:Int),(s2:String,i2:Int))=>(s1+s2,i1+i2))
```

however my IDE show strange error. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: The method signature of the `reduceByKey` lambda depends entirely on the collection you are reducing. What does your collection look like? It must be a collection of `(KeyType, (String, Int))`?

Comment: Also this looks like a case where you are trying to unpack the tuples in the lambda declaration. Unless you use pattern matching the parameters should be `(t1: (String, Int), t2: (String, Int))` instead of what you have

Comment: "my IDE show strange error." ... and the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does

```
reduceByKey({case((s1:String,i1:Int),(s2:String,i2:Int))=>(s1+s2,i1+i2)})
```

look in your IDE?